# Two mappers with Multiple data sources

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, mapper

I am wrote 2 mappers Map1 and Map2

Map1- reads a seq file in HDFS and processes it.

Map2- reads from HBASE and produces same key,value pair as Map1.

Finally I merge them in ReducerAll.

The problem is that only one of the mappers is running and the job completes wihtout any kind of error. Only the last mapper is running (i.e `TableMapReduceUtil`). If I exchange the lines `TableMapReduceUtil` and `MultipleInputs`, then the last one i.e. `MultipleInputs` mapper runs.

What am I doing wrong here? No errors are thrown for both scenarios. I also read 2 files using `addCacheFile()` for processing but that does not matter here I guess.

```
Job job3 = Job.getInstance(config, "Test");
if (true) {


  job3.setJarByClass(Main.class);


  job3.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
  job3.setMapOutputValueClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
  job3.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
  job3.setOutputValueClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);


  job3.getConfiguration().set("StartDate", c_startDate);
  job3.getConfiguration().set("EndDate", c_endDate);


  job3.addCacheFile(new URI(args[8]));
  job3.getConfiguration().set("abc", args[8].substring(args[8].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

  job3.addCacheFile(new URI(args[9]));
  job3.getConfiguration().set("xyz", args[9].substring(args[9].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
  job3.setReducerClass(ReducerAll.class);
  job3.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

  job3.setNumReduceTasks(10);

  Scan scan = new Scan();
  scan.setAttribute(Scan.SCAN_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE_NAME, Bytes.toBytes("hbasetable"));
  scan.setCaching(300);
  scan.setCacheBlocks(false);

  MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job3, new Path(args[6]), SequenceFileInputFormat.class, Map1.class);
  TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
          "hbasetable",
          scan,
          Map2.class,
          ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
          ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
          job3);


  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job3, new Path(args[7]));
  job3.waitForCompletion(true);
  if (!job3.waitForCompletion(true)) {
    return (1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behaviour is because of the following two lines:-

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job3, new Path(args[6]), SequenceFileInputFormat.class, Map1.class);
 TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
      "hbasetable",
      scan,
      Map2.class,
      ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
      ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
      job3);
```

1. There is only one job **job3**
2. Although you have mentioned that there are two mappers, look at the mapper types. The mapper in `Map1` would be *different* from `Map2`. `Map1` is a `Mapper`,  and `Map2` is a `TableMapper`
3. Keeping the two statements together does not mean that they are essentially clubbed in a MultipleInputs *setup* for **job3**. The MultipleInputs still only has **one setup for Map1**. The other setup of Map2 is still separate.
4. Now for the execution. The latter of the two configurations MultipleInputs or TableMapReduceUtil overwrites the previous one in the **job3** and hence only a single mapper executes

PS:- Please let me know if this is incorrect, I am yet to validate my understanding I have presented here on my machine.

Comment: Ah! I understand now. So, if I want to run both mappers and direct it to the same mapper, should I define another job? But, then how will I be able to give it to the same reducer?

Comment: direct it to the same reducer*

Comment: @gambit I think we can use three jobs. First two jobs with only mappers, and a third job(Merge step) with a plain Mapper that practically writes the input to output 'as is'  and then a reducer that actually does a merge task on these files. I am still trying think of a way to do it in better manner (which gives a better performance). Please let me  know if this helps. Will post if I find anything better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456369/mapreduce-job-with-mixed-data-sources-hbase-table-and-hdfs-files

The answer supposedly works and the OP used the same job. The comment has a user facing my problem. Any idea on this?

Comment: My bad. Your scenario is different. For a moment it seemed like his solution can be used to work in this scenario as well. Deleting the older comment to avoid any confusions.